# Gradle много выкачивает из сети

Tags: gradle

Всем привет.

Столкнувшись с Gradle, столкнулся и с проблемой - он закачал (засрал) мне винт, тк выкачал  20Гб в локальную репу. хотя ему нужно всего несколько либ.

вот код:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-solr')
        compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core')
        compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3')
        compile('com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre')

        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}") }
    }
```

**почему он выкачал столько?** (хотя это еще не предел я просто остановил скачивание). Ведь в секции ***repositories*** мы должны указывать где искать нужные нам библиотеки, в данном случае это в *mavenCentral*

Или может это потому что в депенденсях не указаны версии?

я просто всегда работал с Мавеном, а в сети что то ничего не нашел по своему вопросу...

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно у библиотек есть ещё свои зависимости.

Comment: @Streletz - да конечно. **НО** почему мавен при работа с такими же зависимостями выкачивает 20 Мб, а не 20Гб ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение** проблемы оказалось банальным.

**Сменил Idea-14.0.1 на Idea-18.3.2** и все нормализировалось.